# Android Studio, Remove ListView Item without affecting another Item

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, listviewitem

I am making a ToDo List and have troubles with deleting an item from ListView.

If the User has done one thing on his list, he can click on that item and it will be either striked through, or the strike trhough will be undone:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            int i_strikethrough = tv.getPaintFlags();
            if(i_strikethrough == 1297){
                tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            } else if (i_strikethrough == 1281){
                tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
        }
    });
```

If the user makes a long click, a message will pop up and he can choose to delete this item:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    adapterInhalt.remove(adapterInhalt.getItem(position));
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now, my problem is the following:

Imagine the second Item is striked through but the third is not.

If i delete the second Item, then the third Item is at second place and is striked through. But it should not be striked through.

I hope that you understand my problem and that you can help me solving this issue.

I hope this picture will help you understanding the issue:
[A helping Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LgOw.jpg)

Comment: we need to look at your full adapter code..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't implementing a list view properly.  List views recycle views.  This means they reuse the same views and put different positions in your list into them.  This provides very efficient UI code.  It also means that if you make any changes to the view outside of getView of your adapter that those changes will be applied to the wrong item when you remove or scroll.

The write way to make a listview is that if you want to update the UI of any position, you change the model of that position.  THen you tell the adapter that it needs to update by calling notifyDataSetChanged().  The getView function will then get called to redraw each visible element and should apply the strike through.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class for your items, that has a boolean field for strike status. for example:

```
public class MyItem{
    String name;
    boolean isStriked;
}
```

then you can check if an item is striked through on adapter's `getView()` method. you can increase the cohesion in your code this way. BTW I recommend using RecyclerView as it has predefined methods and animations for item deletion

Comment: I did not know that there is something like RecyclerView. Thank you. I will have a lok into it.